# -Firebase- Don't understand the rules

Tags: firebase, rules

After watching movie and read i really don't understand what i want to do.

I'm explain, i have a website, he read information in my database realtime and printed on my website ...

And i got a system for vote, visitor can coming and click on button for send a vote and i sended directly on my server database.

My problem is actually write/read is true and all word but if i pass anyone on false one of two don't work.
But what need to do for nobody can modifi or delete my data ??

The rules is clear i can for who i want (admin,guest,anonymous..) what i want. But is not my problem, i don't understand what i want to do :/

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you better explain your problem and provide example code of what you have tried, I don't understand your desired outcome.

Comment: Hi tom,

Thanks, My problem is what i need to do for nobody can delete or modify my data ?
Actually my firebase datatnase realtime is read/write : true. 

But i read that "For test development is good but after deploying if you let true anyone can call you'r data and modify him".
So i don't now who my website can read my data for display him, and send vote to server. 

But nobody can access my data for modify or delete
( Sorry i do my best i got not good english )

Thanks you

Comment: Are you using the Realtime Database or Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have explained in your comment I think you want to make the firebase rules read-only?

If this is true the following code will accomplish that:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you could allow writing tp database only if a user is authenticated (signed in):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

more information on firestore rules can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview?authuser=0